# What in the world is T*& return type

Tags: c++

I have been looking at vector implementations and stumbled upon a line that confuses me as a naive C++ learner.

1. What is `T*&` return type?
2. Is this merely a reference to a pointer?
3. Why would this be useful then?

link to code: https://github.com/questor/eastl/blob/56beffd7184d4d1b3deb6929f1a1cdbb4fd794fd/vector.h#L146

```
T*& internalCapacityPtr() EASTL_NOEXCEPT { return mCapacityAllocator.first(); }
```

Comment: A reference to a pointer is useful the same times you might want a pointer to a pointer.   When you want to refer to a pointer elsewhere instead of a copy of the pointer.  Also if you read the type right to left it will tell you what the type is.   Reference.  Pointer. T.

Comment: I think it lets you do `internalCapacityPtr()=someAddressValue;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. It's a reference-to-a-pointer to a value of type `T` which is passed as a template argument, or rather:

   1. There exists an instance of `VectorBase<T>` where `T` is specified by the program, `T` could be `int`, `string` or anything.
   2. The `T` value exists as an item inside the vector.
   3. A pointer to the item can be created: `T* pointer = &this->itemValues[123]`
   4. You can then create a reference to this pointer: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1sf8shae.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396
2. Correct
3. If you need to use a value "indirectly" then references-to-pointers are cheaper to use than pointer-to-pointers as the compiler/CPU doesn't need to perform a double-indirection.

Comment: Code using a reference-to-pointer and code using a pointer-to-pointer will very often result in identical machine-level code and identical performance.

Comment: Don't forget you can assign the referenced value which wouldn't be the case with a `T*`.

Comment: I think number 3 ain't correct, often they are modeled the same (except for nullptr behavior). An optimizing compiler will have more effect that this nullptr check, as it can deduce if the pointer is allowed to be nullptr from how you use it. The real added value is that the programmer knows it ain't nullptr without checking the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html

This would be a reference to a pointer of type T. References to pointers can be a bit tricky but are used a lot with smart pointers when using a reference saves an increment to the reference counter.

Answer (score 0):

Types in C++ should be read from right to left. Following this, it becomes a: Reference to a pointer of T. So your assumption is correct.

References to pointers are very useful, this is often used as an output argument or an in-out argument. Let's consider a specific case of std::swap

```
template <typename T>
void swap(T*& lhs, T*& rhs) {
    T *tmp = rhs;
    rhs = lhs;
    lhs = tmp;
 }
```

As with every type, it can be used as return value. In the  state library, you can find this return type for `std::vector<int *>::operator[]`, allowing `v[0] = nullptr`.

On the projects that I've worked on, I haven't seen much usages of this kind of getters that allow changing the internals. However, it does allow you to write a single method for reading and writing the value of the member.

In my opinion, I would call it a code smell as it makes it harder to understand which callers do actual modifications.
The story is off course different when returning a const reference to a member, as that might prevent copies. Though preventing the copy of a pointer doesn't add value.